# hiding / showing sections for forms depending on date

Tags: vba, excel

just a query more than anything. Not sure if im allowed to just ask a question on here without submitting code? but anyway here goes.

Wondering whether it is possible in Excel using vba to show/hide sections of a form depending on what date it is. The form i'm creating will be used for audits and each month a different audit is completed. The form will be used as described below.

Workbook opens ---- user enters a patient id number (lookup function used to retrieve data from database(I DON'T NEED HELP WITH THIS BIT) ----- user chooses yes / no from dropdown

yes - shows relevant form depending on date
no  - leaves form as is.

Can't think of a suitable way to tackle set the form up and dont know how to show/hide sections so any suggestions would be grateful.

Comment: Do you mean a form as in a userform or a worksheet that has been crafted to look like a form?

Comment: @Remnant - worksheet that has been crafted to look like a form. I see where you're coming from though as i could add buttons to the worksheet so the user can select which form they want to fill out. But the forms are long and messy and would sit better on a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little open-ended and clearly there isn't a definitive answer. Here are some of my intial thoughts:

**If your forms only vary slightly** (i.e. 90% the same and only 10% is variable) and it is only a certain section(s) of the form that varies, then maybe create each section and then selectively hide.

For example, suppose I have a section that is different depending upon whether the user is male of female. I could build both sections and then show / hide as follows:

```
If gender = "Male" Then
    Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True //Assume you built male section in rows 10 to 20
    Range("20:30").EntireRow.Hidden = false //Assume you built female section in 20 to 30
Else // replicate code for female scenario
    Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("20:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End if
```

**If your forms vary a lot** (i.e. only 10% static and 90% variable) my experience is that you are better off building each form separately in a different worksheet and then displaying accordingly:

```
If gender = "Male" Then
     Worksheets("maleForm").Visible = True
Else
     Worksheets("femaleForm").Visible = True
End if
```

**If your input fields differ** then you can consider disabling certain fields selectively:

```
 If gender = "Male" Then
      Worksheets("myForm").OLEObjects("lipstickDropDown").Enabled = False //Using Control Toolbox items e.g. textbox, combobox etc...
      Worksheets("myForm").OLEObjects("beerDropDown").Enabled = True
 Else
      Worksheets("myForm").OLEObjects("lipstickDropDown").Enabled = True 
      Worksheets("myForm").OLEObjects("beerDropDown").Enabled = False
 End if
```

If I can add to this later I will do. Does any of this help you out?

Comment: Many thanks Remnant. Thats the sort of advice i was looking for. Just couldn't quite think how to do it. I think showing the forms over different worksheets would work better. Thanks again